# What are multiple scientificly plausible methods of faster then light travel

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, travel, faster-than-light, dyson-spheres

I'm trying to figure out several methods of FTL, that are actually theoretically possible.

ALSO, What would be a viable method of high-speed travel, particularly in a Dyson-sphere (Well, A chunk of one anyway)?

Comment: In this form your question is unfortunately not suitable for this platform.
Consider asking this in a forum or have look at this : http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/FTL.html

Comment: Feels like a duplicate of this: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/363/is-there-a-scientifically-sound-faster-than-light-travel-system-for-a-spaceship?rq=1

Comment: Search the **existing** questions for these tags.

Comment: Hi, CaptClockobob, welcome to Worldbuilding, sorry if this hasn't been the warmest of welcomes, but questions about FTL travel are asked often & aren't well received. Despite that, you asked about theoretical FTL, which is sensible, because science allows for some theoretical modes of FTL, but that doesn't make them real. Here there is generally a strong line against FTL. It's takes time to learn ropes here. Don't let this discourage you. WB keeps its standards high. This produces quality answers to questions. Hope you understand.

Comment: A suggestion: the part of your question about high-speed Dyson sphere travel is better fit for being a question in its own right. Please give details about the structure of your dyson sphere to help answers. Dyson spheres come in several varieties: dyson swarms, dyson shells, dyson bubbles, etc. For more information try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere

Comment: The most scientifically plausible FTL technology is one that involves the current crop of scientists being wrong in some way.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few theoretical proposals for faster-than-light phenomena. There is absolutely no guarantee they will lead to faster-than-light travel.

The basic theoretical FTL methods include: --

- wormholes
- the Alcubierre drive
- Krashnikov tubes

It is recommended you look at previous questions on Worldbuilding SE for further information. See above for URL.

The Wikipedia entry on [Faster-than-light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light) is a good startling point for research. It will lead you to the theoretical concepts listed above.

This is a popular question and gets asked here often.